# lan with multiple ip

Tags: ip, subnet, mac-address, lan

If imagine lan assigned ip from from this range (192.168.1.0/24) then can we assign another ip from same subnet mask? If no why?

Comment: Yah but u didn't explain why can't we assign another ip from same subnet mask like 192.168.1.5 and 172.168.1.3?

Comment: By networking standards, there's nothing stopping you. A host might not allow any of that but what a host does or doesn't do is off-topic here, see the [help].